# How to Navigate to Next Page With Images in ListViewBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

[[image]
I want to make the list a will navigate to List route

Comment: Can you post the code directly and not the image?

Comment: do you mean click on image and it sends you to anew page?

Comment: can you make your question a bit more descriptive?

Comment: @griffins yes, i want to make all of the images have their own link that sends to a new page. I have so many images so i need to use ListView.builder i guess

Answer (score 0):

wrap your list tile with inkwell

```
InkWell(
        onTap: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, "nextpage"), 
        child: yourWidget, )
```